# The position of pop up div changes over scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, popup

I want to pop up a div just on the position where I click the page. So I have the following HTML.

```
<HTML>
<body>
    <button id="popupButton"> click </button>
    <div id="popupFilterDiv" class="popupFilterDiv" style="display:none;">
          <input type="checkbox" name="statusFilter" value="Active" /> Active <br />
          <input type="checkbox" name="statusFilter" value="Expired" /> Expired <br />
            </div>
</body>
</HTML>
```

the js is:

```
$("#popupButton").live('click', function (e) {
    leftVal = e.pageX + "px";
    topVal = e.pageY + "px";
    $('#popupFilterDiv').css({ left: leftVal, top: topVal }).show();
});
```

and css is:

```
.popupFilterDiv
{
    background-color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #999999;
    cursor:default;
    display:none;
    margin-top: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:50;
    padding: 15px 15px 5px;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```

Now, everything works well except that, when I change the width of the web browser, the pop up div lies far away from the popupButton, and the shape of the pop up div also changed.

What I expected is

[image]

while when I change the width of the web browser, it becomes disordered.

[image]

Comment: You should have to get offset position of your button, and display popup accordingly, and call this function on window re-size as well

Comment: +1 for posting all relevant information

Answer (score 0):

It may not be very elegant, but you could give your `.popupFilterDiv` class a fixed width:

```
.popupFilterDiv
{
    /*other relevant styles*/
    position: absolute;
    width: 50px; /* set a fixed width */
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}
```